# Display selected image in other page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my aspx page there is datalist contains an image and a checkbox.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5">        
    <ItemTemplate>
     <table cellspacing="2"  id="tbItem">
       <tr>       
        <td align="center" >            
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgLnk" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/gallery/imgs/"+Eval("Image") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr><td align="center">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />       
    </td></tr></table>           
    </ItemTemplate>     
</asp:DataList>
```

If the checkbox is checked for whichever images, that images should shown in an other page on a button click.

Comment: are you talking about only one image can be selected at a time or more than one image may be selected?

Comment: Want to select multiple images

Comment: so selecting multiple images means opening all selected images in single or in respective windows ?

Comment: Below each image there is a checkbox, and a button also there below the datalist. By clicking the button, which ever checkboxes checked respective images should shown in an other page.

Comment: so whats the problem?? have u wrote click event...

Answer (score 0):

Add one HiddenField with CheckBox which has the value of required id.....

Add this code on button click....

```
    string str = "";
    foreach (DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dli.FindControl("chkSelect");
        HiddenField hdf = (HiddenField)dli.FindControl("HiddenField1");


        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            str += hdf.value + ",";
        }
    }

   //Redirect str as query string and fetch there, split and its done..
```

Do let me know if u want more help....or if this dosen't work...

Comment: can you tell me please what is chk.cw;

Comment: dude i tried to pass the str value to other page, but its null

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52656/discussion-between-x-developer-and-user2772568)